# Making Absolute XPath more robust for testing

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

I'm new to the test automation world and been teaching myself.

On the internet challenging DOM page, I have located the blue button using the absolute Xpath, it was the only was I could think of to locate it. Every other selector seems to change dynamically as the page is refreshed.

Is there a way to make this selection more robust in this case? From googling it seems to be a fragile method of locating something on a webpage.

https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/challenging_dom

```
''' #Test blue button on page, repeated 5 times and text displayed checked against options. 
@pytest.mark.repeat(5)
def test_2():
    elem1 = b.find_element(By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a[1]')
    a=(elem1.text)`enter code here`
    elem1.click()
    assert a in Names
    print (a)'''
```

Comment: Please try this and let me know xPath = //a[@class='button' and text()='foo']

Comment: This should work in your case `//a[contains(@class, 'button') and position() = 1]`. Also, `position() = 1` will select the first button, you can change the value based on which one do you want to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the blue color button has this HTML

```
<a id="240aa520-d0f5-0139-b953-067df9ace5fa" href="" class="button">bar</a>
```

it's pretty much clear that `id` is getting generated `dynamically`.

`href` does **not** have any `value`.

`class` is `button` and `text` is `bar` (but text is keep on changing so we **will not consider text** as well)

so based on class, we can construct a `xpath` :

```
//a[@class='button']
```

Now the problem is we have multiple entry in DOM, right ?

so in this case we are left with 2 options :-

1. `Xpath index`
2. `find_elements`

Using xpath indexing :

first button :-

```
 (//a[@class='button'])[1]
```

or

for second button :-

```
 (//a[@class='button'])[2]
```

and so on..

2. Using find_elements :

   ```
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button']")

    buttons[0].click()  # to click on first button

    buttons[1].click()  # to click on second button
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The correct and unique XPath for this element can be

```
//a[@class='button']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the three-button has the dynamic id value So I have just try to check with the static part of the id which is common for all the buttons and we get the desired button based on the index.

```
((//a[contains(@id,'067df9ace5fa')])[1])
```

Text of the button is getting changed but the attribute remains the same so you can check it below

```
//a[@class='button']
```